# ALM C# application

Tags: c#, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I am using `Interop.TDAPIOLELib` dll to connect to ALM (application lifecycle managment).

In order to connect to the project i am using `TDConnection` but when executing this line

```
 _connection = new TDAPIOLELib.TDConnection();
```

i get this exception

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C5CBD7B2-490C-45F5-8C40-B8C3D108E6D7} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

This code was working fine before i repaired my HD

I run `sfc/scannow` and i got this message `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations`. Which indicate that i do not have any missing or corrupted system files.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OTAClient.dll` should be registered 
using `regsvr32.exe` register the `OTAClient.dll` it located in this path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Mercury Interactive\TDAPIClient` and make sure that the application is run under x86 target.

Comment: QC 11 this file is located at C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\HP\ALM-Client\qualitycenter

Answer (score 4):

It's necesary to download the TDConnect.exe

1. Go to your HP ALM web interface
2. 'Tool' link
3. 'HP ALM Connectivity' link
4. Click on 'Download HP ALM Connectivity'

it will download TDConnect.exe file, you need to do this trhu your instance to match the TDConnect.exe with your version, for example if you are running HP ALM 11.52 you MUST download the TDConnect.exe for this version.

Comment: Can also be downloaded directly here: https://almpc.sqa.its.state.nc.us/qcbin/TDConnectivity_index.html. Running this installer fixed my issues using the TDAPI..dll

Comment: Another direct download link is https://qc.migros.net/qcbin/TDConnectivity_index.html . It works with 11.0.0.7051 (while he one above didn't).

Answer (score 0):

although this is an old question, but sharing what worked for me - the solution mentioned here - http://www.juvander.fi/site/Forums/tabid/129/forumid/2/threadid/14/scope/posts/Default.aspx

may help someone if nothing else works