# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C5CBD7B2-490C-45F5-8C40-B8C3D108E6D7}

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, iis, com

I able to add my ASP.NET application on IIS. And when I browse my application I am able to successfully login to my application. But when I button click on Login I am getting

```
Error "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C5CBD7B2-490C-45F5-8C40-B8C3D108E6D7} 
failed due to the following error:80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). I am able to do all operations on my application locally

. I tried republishing my application
. Checked all the authorization access
```

But still couldnot figure it out

Comment: You need a COM object that is not installed on the machine, or unavailable (often for permissions issues), or not in the expected bitness (x86 vs x64). This COM object seems related to some HP software: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606986/alm-c-sharp-application

Comment: I tried this before even my code is using HP ALM. It is installed on my machine

Comment: Thank you @SimonMourier  . [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606986/alm-c-sharp-application) helped in analyzing.. I have  developed web application on 32 bit machine with QC code and trying to host on 64bit machine. After commenting Qc code and rehost my web application is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed web application on 32 bit machine with belowde:

TDAPIOLELib.TDConnection td=new TDAPIOLELib.TDConnection();

and trying to host on 64bit machine. After commenting Qc code and rehost my web application is working fine.

I have QC installed on 64bit server machine too I am surprised why it is not working with QC